# Выбор файла по кнопке в plugin qgis

Tags: python, плагин, pyqt, qgis

Для плагина qgis необходимо чтобы по кнопке pushButton открывалось окно для выбора файла (например area.shp), после клика по файлу в поле lineEdit нужно чтобы отображался путь к нему, например `/home/userName/docs/area.shp`.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

def run(self):
    # Run method that loads and starts the plugin

    if not self.pluginIsActive:
        self.pluginIsActive = True

        print("** STARTING ClassName")

        # dockwidget may not exist if:
        #    first run of plugin
        #    removed on close (see self.onClosePlugin method)
        if self.dockwidget == None:
            # Create the dockwidget (after translation) and keep reference
            self.dockwidget = ClassNameDockWidget()

        # connect to provide cleanup on closing of dockwidget
        self.dockwidget.closingPlugin.connect(self.onClosePlugin)

        # show the dockwidget
        # TODO: fix to allow choice of dock location
        self.iface.addDockWidget(Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self.dockwidget)
        self.dockwidget.show()

        def directory():
            title = "Select a file"
            flags = QFileDialog()
            dirpath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(title, '', flags)
            print(dirpath)
            self.dockwidget.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(dirpath)
        self.dockwidget.pushButton.clicked.connect(directory)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо строк:

```
flags = QFileDialog()
dirpath = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(title, '', flags)
print(dirpath)
```

Вставьте вот эти:

```
# Фильтр нужных файлов
filter = "GIS Files (*.shp)" # убрала <;> потому что с ней питон не видел файлов

# Диалоговое окно выбора файла
filename, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "Select the gis-file", "./", filter)

# Выводим имя файла и путь к нему, если пользователь нажал кнопку "Принять",
# иначе пустую строку
self.dockwidget.lineEdit.setText(filename)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало, только тут 

`# Фильтр нужных файлов
filter = "GIS Files (*.shp)" ` 

надо убрать точку с запятой - ;
это опечатка? или на других ОС она может быть нужна?

Comment: @Hany в данном случае точка с запятой не нужна, но если у вас несколько групп типов файлов, то их можно перечислять: "Group (*.ext, *.ext2); Group2 (*.gext, *.gext2); ..."

Comment: Понятно, спасибо за пояснение, очень помогли!